# Any good simple DirectX samples for Windows 8 (Developer preview)?

Tags: c#, c++, directx, windows-8

Are there any good tutorials on how to draw a simple triangle in DirecX for Windows 8 Developer preview? The game sample is too complex to understand the "basic" workings of the new DirectX version (which seems to be completely different from DirectX 9).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of the sample is the Windows 8, not the DirectX. You need to learn DirectX11 *before* doing it with Windows 8. You're trying to read a sample on interoperation between two technologies, neither of which you understand. The point of Windows 8 Dev Preview is not to teach DirectX.

Comment: They completely changed DirectX though in Windows 8. It's not at all the same as previous versions; so DirectX is PART of Windows 8. They don't seem to have good documentation on DirectX either (DirectX for Windows 8 is different than DirectX for Windows 7)

Comment: @IDWMaster I've never heard of any DirectX 12, yet. And the DirectX 11.1 of Windows 8 shouldn't be that different from the DirectX 11 you can already use in Windows 7. Of course it's different from DirectX 9, but that is not the last version you can use in Windows Vista (DX10) or 7 (DX11).

Comment: Thought DX11 was Windows 8 specific, but it turns out it's quite similar to the existing DirectX 11 for Windows 7.

Comment: @IDWMaster: Yes, there's nothing Windows 8 about DX11, it's been in Vista and Windows 7 for some time now. DX9 hasn't been current for some years.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. See code below. Only thing that doesn't work is the texture (it shows as white instead of displaying the image, but at least it displays the triangle!) (This code isn't obviously the whole program. Turns out it involves quite a lot of complex code to just draw a triangle these days!)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ManagedDirectX;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
namespace TestProgram
{
    public sealed class EntryPoint
    {
        public void NtfyExecutionAbrt()
        {
        }

        public EntryPoint()
        {
            beginexecblock();
        }
        void onrenderframe()
        {
            if(vertcount>0) {
                maincontext.Draw(vertcount);
            }
        }
        int vertcount = 0;
        Shader defaultshader;
        RenderContext maincontext;
        async void beginexecblock()
        {
            if ((await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.GetFilesAsync()).Count == 0)
            {
                await ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.CreateFileAsync("testfile.txt");
                ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChanged();
                Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog tdlg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Roaming file creation success", "Sync status");
                await tdlg.ShowAsync();    
            }
            try
            {
                DateTime started = DateTime.Now;
                RenderContext mtext = new RenderContext();
                maincontext = mtext;
                StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
                StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("DXInteropLib\\VertexShader.cso");

                var stream = (await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
                Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader mreader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
                byte[] dgram = new byte[file.Size];
                await mreader.LoadAsync((uint)dgram.Length);
                mreader.ReadBytes(dgram);
                file = await folder.GetFileAsync("DXInteropLib\\PixelShader.cso");

                stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                mreader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
                byte[] mgram = new byte[file.Size];
                await mreader.LoadAsync((uint)file.Size);
                mreader.ReadBytes(mgram);
                try
                {
                    defaultshader = mtext.CreateShader(dgram, mgram);
                    mtext.InitializeLayout(dgram);
                    defaultshader.Apply();
                    mtext.OnRenderFrame += onrenderframe;
                }
                catch (Exception er)
                {
                    Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog mdlg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(er.ToString(),"Fatal error");
                    mdlg.ShowAsync().Start();
                }
                IStorageFile[] files = (await folder.GetFilesAsync()).ToArray();
                bool founddata = false;
                foreach (IStorageFile et in files)
                {
                    if (et.FileName.Contains("rawimage.dat"))
                    {
                        stream = await et.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                        founddata = true;
                    }
                }
                int width;
                int height;
                byte[] rawdata;
                if (!founddata)
                {
                    file = await folder.GetFileAsync("TestProgram\\test.png");
                    stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                    var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                    var pixeldata = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTransform(), Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
                    width = (int)decoder.PixelWidth;
                    height = (int)decoder.PixelHeight;

                    rawdata = pixeldata.DetachPixelData();
                    file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("rawimage.dat");
                    stream = (await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite));
                    var realstream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
                    DataWriter mwriter = new DataWriter(realstream);
                    mwriter.WriteInt32(width);
                    mwriter.WriteInt32(height);
                    mwriter.WriteBytes(rawdata);
                    await mwriter.StoreAsync();
                    await realstream.FlushAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    DataReader treader = new DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
                    await treader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                    rawdata = new byte[stream.Size-(sizeof(int)*2)];
                    width = treader.ReadInt32();
                    height = treader.ReadInt32();
                    treader.ReadBytes(rawdata);
                }
                Texture2D mtex = maincontext.createTexture2D(rawdata, width, height);
                List<VertexPositionNormalTexture> triangle = new List<VertexPositionNormalTexture>();
                triangle.Add(new VertexPositionNormalTexture(new Vector3(-.5f,-.5f,0),new Vector3(1,1,1),new Vector2(0,0)));
                triangle.Add(new VertexPositionNormalTexture(new Vector3(0,0.5f,0),new Vector3(1,1,1),new Vector2(1,0)));
                triangle.Add(new VertexPositionNormalTexture(new Vector3(.5f,-0.5f,0),new Vector3(1,1,1),new Vector2(1,1)));
                byte[] gpudata = VertexPositionNormalTexture.Serialize(triangle.ToArray());

                VertexBuffer mbuffer = maincontext.createVertexBuffer(gpudata,VertexPositionNormalTexture.Size);
                mbuffer.Apply(VertexPositionNormalTexture.Size);
                vertcount = 3;
                Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog tdlg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Unit tests successfully completed\nShader creation: Success\nTexture load: Success\nVertex buffer creation: Success\nTime:"+(DateTime.Now-started).ToString(), "Results");
                tdlg.ShowAsync().Start();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog tdlg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(er.ToString(), "Fatal error");
                tdlg.ShowAsync().Start();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Only native C++ is supported to write DirectX11 games.